# installshield for class library COM interop project

Tags: c#, vba, excel, installshield

I have created a Class Library project with some COM visible types. The project is installed via InstallShield.

To ensure proper registration of my assembly, I have defined the following in the build events:

```
"%Windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\regasm" /codebase /tlb 
"$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\$(OutputPath)$(AssemblyName).dll"
```

I am trying to use this **tlb** file in vba. When I build the solution it is creating the **tlb** file and I am able to add that tlb file as **reference** and use it in VBA.

I created an installer for this project and added `.dll and .tlb` files in the project files in InstallShield

I installed the library in another system, and the `.dll and .tlb` files were present in the installation folder (C:/program files/Project/Name.dll)

But when I refer to that `tlb` file, and then try to create an object from it, VBA throws a `429 can't create object` error.

In the classlibrary project properties - Platform target, I have tried `Any CPU` as well as `x64`

Comment: You might check to ensure all the dependencies are installed on the target machine. Might have have one that is present on your box, so it works, but fails on the other box.

Comment: should i add the dll files i am referring to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below you'll find an excerpt [from my blog](https://christopherjmcclellan.wordpress.com/2015/02/25/registering-a-com-add-in-with-installsheild-le/) that may help. I'm not 100% certain that you're facing the same issue that I was, but you may be.

> Go to the Project Assistant, and then to the Application Files screen.
>   You’ll need to take a couple of Actions here to properly create the
>   installer. Obviously, you’ll need to add the Primary Output. What’s
>   not so obvious is that you’ll also need to manually link the *.tlb
>   file by selecting installation folder, then the Add File button, and
>   pointing to the file in your \bin\Release directory.
>
> [image: Installshield Files Screen]
>
> The second not so obvious (and most frustrating) thing is you’ll need
>   to set the properties on the assembly correctly. So, right click on
>   the Primary Output, and select Properties. In the dialog, go to the
>   COM & .Net Settings tab. Once you’re there, use the settings below.
>
> - Extract COM Information
> - Scan at Build == Dependencies and Properties
> - Check the COM Interop box.
>
> [image: Com & .Net Settings]
>
> You’ll need to do the same for the *.tlb file, only ***don’t*** check
>   the COM Interop box this time.

---

Another possibility is that you have a class that should have the `ComVisible` attribute that isn't, or you're missing the com visible interface that VBA needs to connect to the server.

As was mentioned in the comments, you may also be missing a dependency that your *.dll needs to function. I ran into that issue once. Installshield only picks up the files that are *directly* inside of the `bin\release\` directory. If one of your dependencies are creating a *sub*-directory, say `bin\release\someDirectory\someFile.dll`, then you will need a custom post-build on your project to copy the dependency into the release folder prior to the installer build.

Comment: I should have asked sooner. What version of installshield are you using? If you right click on the files you added to the out put, you should see a properties option that opens the dialog in the second image.

Comment: ya got that !
i need not add the .dll or .dll.config file?

Comment: in the bin/debug folder i have .tlb file, .dll file
should i add .tlb file alone or .dll  also needs to be added

Comment: You'll need them both. Check the COM Interop box for the dll, but not the tlb.

Comment: oh okay!! will try
and how can i handle for 64bit and 32 bit?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77342/discussion-between-vignesh-and-rubberduck).